# How to quickly serialize Clojure data structures to string with indentations?

Tags: serialization, clojure, indentation

clojure.pprint seems to do what I want:

```
user=> (def a {"q" {:q 1 :w 2 :e 3 :r 4 :t 4}, "w" {:q 1 :w 2 :e 3 :r 4 :t 4} "e" {:q 1 :w 2 :e 3 :r 4 :t 4}, "r" {:q 1 :w 2 :e 3 :r 4 :t 4}})
user=> (pprint a)
{"e" {:r 4, :e 3, :w 2, :t 4, :q 1},
 "q" {:r 4, :e 3, :w 2, :t 4, :q 1},
 "r" {:r 4, :e 3, :w 2, :t 4, :q 1},
 "w" {:r 4, :e 3, :w 2, :t 4, :q 1}}
nil
```

but

```
user=> (time (with-out-str (pprint a)))
"Elapsed time: 174.621945 msecs"
...
user=> (time (do (with-out-str (pprint (repeat 1000 {:r 4 :t 6 :q 3 :u 5 :d 3}))) nil))
"Elapsed time: 32902.028436 msecs"
```

it is too slow.

Are there any printers in Clojure which does indentation (maybe not as accurately as pprint), but is also fast and suitable for big structures?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into Brandon Bloom's [Fipp](https://github.com/brandonbloom/fipp) (GitHub repo summary: "Fast Idiomatic Pretty Printer for Clojure"). Note that the README states that it's [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn)-only for now.

Comment: `(time (do (with-out-str (fipp (repeat 1000 [{:q 3 :d 4} 5]))) nil))` -> 11527 msecs vs 215 for usual `print`.

Comment: Right now, fipp is about twice as fast as clojure's pprint, but (as Vi has discovered) far and away from prn. There are lots of opportunities for optimizations in fipp, but I'm not sure where the bottom is.

Comment: Note: the developer of fipp have just speeded it up in about 3 times (by using protocols instead of multimethods). Still much slower than just prn...

Comment: Fipp 0.2.0-SNAPSHOT is now about 5 times faster than clojure.pprint, but still 50 to 100 times slower than prn... I've also submitted a perf patch to Clojure and have a quite a few other improvements that can be made. I want to keep Fipp idiomatic and avoid too many perf hacks, but I think I can get close enough to be reasonable to default to pretty printing.

Comment: I think Fipp is pretty awesome as it stands and is the best tool for the job that I currently know of (hence the answer), but certainly I can easily believe that for some use cases the perf hit might be too large. Not sure what to do about that short of rethinking when the pretty printing should happen. (Assuming the formatting is for the benefit of humans, why not see if it can be done just-in-time in some viewer etc. Absolutely not claiming that this would be appropriate here, since the question contains no indication of what the use case is.)

Comment: @BrandonBloom: Since we're on the subject of Fipp, congrats on the great lib! If you can get the sort of perf you're hinting at, well, that'll be amazing. :-)